# MobileFirst 7.1 Community Edition

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I would like to know if there is any community or free edition of MobileFirst which can be used for small scale projects ?

Comment: According to our [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidance, "**Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**...Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic..."

Answer (score 0):

There is not. There is the development edition for development time, and the enterprise/consumer edition for going to production (contains the required tools and artifacts).